# Razor changing table css

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a table in asp.net MVC using razor when the table contains a value that equals 0 i would like to set the  background as red.

The following is my razor code

```
@{int Melt1 = int.Parse(@ViewData["Melt1"].ToString());
                       if (Melt1.Equals(0))
                       {
                            <td class="MeltTableZero td">
                            @ViewData["Melt1"].ToString()
                            </td>
                       }
```

I am doing a check to see if in Melt1 = 0. then if this is true set background as red.

I have tried a number of different ways with the above such as == instead of .equals but i think its the razor code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Melt1` really is an `int`:

```
<td class="MeltTableZero td @((int)ViewData["Melt1"] == 0 ? "red" : null)">
@ViewData["Melt1"].ToString()
</td>
```

Will add a CSS class `red` to your `<td>`:

```
.MeltTableZero.red {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```